# File Monitoring Service (VB)

Tags: vb.net, file, service, system, monitor

I am designing a service in VB (VS 2012) that monitors file system activity. Is there some sort of API or code library that allows the service to detect when:

1. A file is created.
2. When an application file (.exe, .com, .bat) is executed?
3. A folder is opened?

Comment: get googling .. do it by yourself .. when you got stuck .. come back here ..

Comment: I did 'get googling'. I got nothing, Google gives me irrelevant search results. That is why I came here for answers. I think it will benefit not only me but future users if we can work out something on Stackoverflow.